# Ember App Kit: How to deal with Application-wide Singleton instances?

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

Let's say I have the following `app.js` file (currently not using EAK, `Ember 1.4.0`, `Handlebars 1.3.0`, `jQuery 2.1.0`) which sets up different "Singleton" instances which could be accessed through `App.#name` within the whole application (not only `Controllers`, `Routes` or `Views` but also `Helpers`, custom `Utils` and many more ...) like:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.CustomAjax = App.utils.ajax.CustomAjax.create({secHash: 'someSecurityHash'});
App.BrowserStateListener = App.utils.browser.BrowserStateListener.create();
App.UserManager = App.utils.user.CustomUserManager.create({user: App.utils.user.User.create({}), someOtherDependency: RAApp.utils.some.SomeOtherDependency.create({someValue: 'someValue'})});
....
```

... and many more like this.

How would I transfer this into ES6-Modules so that I can use EAK for this application? Should I use `Ember.Application.initializer` for this purpose, so that I can reference the application from withtin the `application` parameter of the `initialize` method like this?

```
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import CustomAjax from 'appkit/utils/ajax/custom-ajax';

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
  LOG_MODULE_RESOLVER: true,
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
  modulePrefix: 'appkit', // TODO: loaded via config
  Resolver: Resolver['default']
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'init1',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
    // set it like this?
    application.CustomAjax = CustomAjax.create({secHash: 'someSecurityHash'});
  }
});

export default App;
```

But then, how would I `import` only the `CustomAjax` object - or any other object I set up like this? If I try to `import App from 'appkit/app'` I won't get the whole application namespace, do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at injecting these objects as dependencies on all your Ember objects:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'init1',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
    var customAjax = App.utils.ajax.CustomAjax.create({secHash: 'someSecurityHash'});
    container.register('custom:ajax', customAjax);
    // inject this object into all ember controllers
    container.injection('controller', 'custom:ajax', 'customAjax');
  }
}):

App.SomeController = Ember.ObjecctController.extend({
    // this object will be injected upon instantiation
    customAjax: null   
}):
```

There is a [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/mixonic/containers-di) on Ember dependency injection by Matt Beale.

Also, if you need to modify ajax requests before they are sent, you can use the Ember.$.ajaxSetup hook.

Comment: thanks a lot for the link! as I found out it is possible to access the `App` as well as the `Ember` namespace in every single object/file/class so I can just place the initialization into the `Ember.Application.initializer` object... and yes, I know about the `ajaxSetup` hook of `jQuery.ajax` but this would change the whole setup for all ajax calls and that's not what I need right now :)